# Can't figure out cause for “Unexpected token ILLEGAL”

Tags: javascript, token

I'm getting an Unexpected token ILLEGAL error message on the following line and can't figure out why. Is it an invisible error or am I just missing something?

```
var currentPop = prompt(“What is the current sheep population?”);
```

Comment: Those quotes....

Comment: Use real quote characters, not that MS Word curly quote stuff. JavaScript isn't MS Word.

Comment: `var currentPop = prompt("What is the current sheep population?");`

Comment: In ES5 only `'` and `"` quotes are allowed for string literals. In ES6, also `\`` quotes are allowed (which have slightly different meaning). You're using some non-standard quotes.

Comment: In general you should avoid copy-pasting code through certain tools (like MS Word, Wordpress etc...) which often replace `"` into `“`.